# Import pandas exits python console

Tags: python, pandas, crash

I ran

```
pip install pandas
```

It completed successfully

In my python console If I run

```
import pandas as pd
```

python exits without any error message. How to debug the root cause of this issue ?

```
auhuman% python           
Python 3.6.14 (default, Jul 15 2021, 16:24:18) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
auhuman%
```

```
auhuman% python -c "import pandas as pd"
auhuman%
```

I tailed my syslog and nothing shows up there

```
tail -f /var/logs/syslog.log
```

Comment: what happens when you run from the command prompy `python -c "import pandas"`? this should trigger the error from the outside, you should see some exceptions? If you are on Linux, you can also look in `syslog` to see possible descriptions of the crash

Comment: _Probably_ it's your python/pandas version conflict. `pandas` 1.3.0 officially supports **Python 3.7.1 and above, 3.8, and 3.9**. So either upgrade your `python` or try installing a previous version that supported 3.6, so anything before `pandas` 1.2.0.

Comment: Thanks ALollz, but I am using pandas 0.22x and it [Officially Python 2.7, 3.5, and 3.6](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/install.html)

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find out the reason?